# Unable to connect RavenDB Cloud, in Microservice (AWS Lambda)

Tags: c#, microservices, ravendb

## Problem statement

Trying to connect RavenDB Cloud service using AWS Lambda function, for one of my POC, but failed to connect.

#### Background

I am using the client certificate (.pfx) file for this. It throws error exactly during certificate assign with X509Certificate2. I have converted the certificate to byte[] and passed. The certificate I am using has full access to the database. I am included the error below

#### Code

```
            if (_bClientCertificate != null)
            {
                if (_bClientCertificate.Length > 0)
                {
                    xclientCertificate = new X509Certificate2(_bClientCertificate);
                }
            }

             IDocumentStore store = new DocumentStore()
            {
                Certificate = xclientCertificate, //Error occured here

                Urls = _Urls,
                Database = _DBName
            }.Initialize();
```

#### Exception Details :

```
System.IO.FileLoadException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=Could not load file or assembly 'Sparrow, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=37f41c7f99471593'. An operation is not legal in the current state. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131509)
  Source=Raven.Client
  StackTrace:
   at Raven.Client.Documents.Subscriptions.DocumentSubscriptions..ctor(IDocumentStore store) in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-4.2\42017\src\Raven.Client\Documents\Subscriptions\DocumentSubscriptions.cs:line 33
   at Raven.Client.Documents.DocumentStoreBase..ctor() in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-4.2\42017\src\Raven.Client\Documents\DocumentStoreBase.cs:line 28
   at Firecloud.DataAccess.RavenDB.SessionStore.CreateStore() in C:\Works\SourceCode\FC\Library\RavenDB\FC.DataAccess.Raven\SessionStore.cs:line 87
   at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
```

[image]

Comment: do you have package sparrow installed?

Comment: No. I installed only RavenDB Client Package.

Comment: Try to install this package. Once I had similar issue with missing package for raven in runtime, manual installtion solved this problem

Comment: I am not sure about the package. Can you please let me know the Nuget package url ?

Comment: Hm, seems that sparrow is part of raven, did you try to install older ravendb version?

Comment: Share your RavenDB.Client version and its dependencies.

Comment: .NET Core 2.1, RavenDB.Client Version 4.2.3 are
Lambda2Js.Signed (3.1.3)
Microsoft.CSharp (4.5.0)
Newtonsoft.Json (12.0.2)
System.Buffers (4.5.0)
System.Memory (4.5.3)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe (4.5.2)
System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation 4.3.0)
System.Security.Cryptography.Cng (4.5.0)
System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions (4.5.3)

Comment: You should have a `Sparrow` dll there as well.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this issue before, apparently some visual C++ libraries could be missing.
Try installing [Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015.](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145)

Comment: Do you have this dll in your project?
_RavenDB.Client.4.2.1\lib\netstandard2.0\Sparrow.dll_

If not, try to install the RavenDB Client again.

Comment: I did that. The same code works in the API project. but not in AWS Lambda functions.